# Aqua data studio export database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, export

How can I export a database from MS SQL to Oracle?
Is it possible?

I create a ER schema in MS SQL then try to convert and generate script. I just need to run it in the Oracle window?

```
CREATE TABLE "dbo"."Categories"  ( 
    "num_categories"    NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    "descriptions"      CHAR(10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Categories" PRIMARY KEY("num_categories")
    NOT DEFERRABLE
     NOVALIDATE
)
```

Comment: also export a inserts

Comment: Can't you use a DSN to connect to Oracle from SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the Database, Go to Tools > ER Diagram Generator, select the Schema, Objects in your source DB and create the ER Model.
2. In the ER Model window, click on Tools > Convert Model and select the Destination Database (Oracle in your case)
3. Make the necessary changes in the Columns and make sure the Datatypes are correct and can be mapped
4. Click on Tools > Generate Script and select all Object Types. In this step scripts for Tables, Views and Indexes will be created.
5. Next, open a Query Analyzer window to Oracle and paste the script that you generated in Step 4.
6. Execute the script in Oracle. Now you have similar scripts as in your Source DB.
7. Navigate to Source DB, select each of the tables, and Export to Excel.
8. Navigate to Destination DB, select the table and Import from Excel.

Links
https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation17/page/76/Generating-ER-Diagrams
https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation17/page/74/How-to-Import-Data